# If Obi-Wan and Yoda were trying to keep Luke safe from Vader, why would they let him keep the Skywalker name?

Tags: star-wars

Obi-Wan and Yoda didn't really make a good effort at hiding him, especially considering they let Vader's family adopt him.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

First, Vader didn't even know he had a son, so there was no reason for him to even look.

Second, Anakin couldn't wait to get off Tatooine, and there was no reason for him to return.  While it was a time with his Mother, it was also where she died and a place where he was a slave, with someone telling him what to do all the time, which is not something a Sith Lord will want to remember.  So Tatooine is probably the one planet Vader would never want to return to.

Third, Obi-Wan was close to Anakin and good friends with him, so he likely wanted to let Anakin's name pass on to another generation.

Fourth, he's staying with his aunt and uncle.  While they don't have the Skywalker name, as relatives (it's never given exactly how close, since uncle and aunt are sometimes vague terms), it wouldn't be too out of place for them to be raising a Skywalker child.

Fifth, sometimes the best place to hide something is in plain sight.

It clearly worked, since Vader was not aware of him until after Luke blew up the *Deathstar* and Vader became obsessed with finding "Young Skywalker."

Comment: His aunt and uncle didnt have the Skywalker name, they where [Owen Lars](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Owen_Lars) and [Beru Whitesun Lars](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Beru_Whitesun_Lars).

Comment: That's right; Shmi Skywalker would have given up her name (or moved it to her middle name) when she married Clieeg Lars. As Anakin was Shmi's only son under the Skywalker name, it should have died out when Anakin became Vader. And Shmi is the oldest known Skywalker, so there are no known Skywalker "cousins".

Comment: @DavRob60: Oops! (Now edited to take care of that.)

Comment: Surely the Skywalker name would have red-flagged somewhere in the Imperial Beauraucracy as soon as a census of Tatooine was made (and the Empire would definitely be the type of government to perform a detailed census - even on a backwater [backdesert?] planet)

Comment: @HorusKol: You're assuming they were looking for the name (there's no reason to), or that the Empire cared enough about a backwater world like Tatooine to track such things on that planet.  But, even then, if there are other families with that name, what reason would Vader have had for watching it?

Comment: @TangoOversway: well, I am relying a bit on the EU, but the Empire is very much the beauraucratic regime that would census a backwater like Tatooine. Also, it might not have been Vader who ordered the flag to be set...

Comment: Sixth, Skywalker may have been a common surname on Tatooine, like Johnson or Smith.

Comment: @RobertF: There is some *Expanded Universe* material that indicates that might be so, actually. In *The New Rebellion*, Luke meets a young mechanic named Cole Fardreamer, and immediately recognises his name as Tatooinian. This would indicate that that style of name is common on Tatooine. This doesn't track with the prequels, which posits that Anakin and Shmi were brought to Tatooine as slaves, rather than originating there, but given other names like 'Darklighter,' 'Fardreamer,' 'Whitesun,' etc., the naming trope does seem to be a Tatooine main-stay.

Comment: Although not canon, TR&FODV has this passage regarding the Skywalker name: "Could there have been other Skywalkers from Tatooine? Vader allowed the possibility. After all, it wasn't an entirely uncommon name in the galaxy." https://books.google.se/books?id=iahp2XZQrwEC&lpg=PA164&ots=vTNgtl-Ena&hl=sv&pg=PA164#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: @HorusKol, Tatooine was indeed a backwater but not exactly under Imperial control, it was a crummy Hutt-controlled planet that the Empire didn't care about. A dusty, uncivilized planet on the fringe of the Galaxy is a good place to hide out, no matter what your name is. Han Solo seemed to think so.

Comment: @ropata indeed, sort of like Kowloon Walled City in the 1970's. It was nominally under the jurisdiction of Hong Kong but in practice it was its own little world ruled by gangsters and unlicensed medical practitioners. If you wanted to disappear there you could, and even if you were wanted and the government knew you were there it was not such an easy task to just "go in" and arrest you.

Comment: I wouldn’t put it past Vader to, once the rebels had been crushed and the war over, use the Death Star (with the Emperor’s blessing) to wipe out Tatooine and a planet of bad memories from existence.

Answer (score 15):

This answer is pretty much conjecture, and dips out of G-Canon, but:

The Emperor had the power to foretell the future (although, whether entirely accurately or not is up for debate).

The Sith have a tradition where, either the apprentice kills the master and takes on a new apprentice, or the master engineers the failure and death of the apprentice and replaces them.

It is entirely possible that the Emperor did know about the Skywalker children, but kept them a secret from Vader as some long-term gambit to force a Sith succession (which the scenes in the Death Star Throne Room can be interpreted as).

Comment: While an interesting theory about the Emperor knowing their identities, this doesn't answer the question of why Obi-Wan et al. let Luke keep his last name.

Answer (score 11):

According to Leland Chee in [*Star Wars Insider #115*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Insider_115), it was Owen and Beru's decision to keep his last name in order to honor Shmi Skywalker. He suggests that either Skywalker was a fairly common name, or that no one made the connection between Luke and Anakin.

> **Why didn't Obi-Wan and Luke change
> their surnames when they were in hiding
> on Tatooine?**
>
> Let's start with Obi-Wan. He's a hermit
> living in a very remote hut on a very
> remote planet that Obi-Wan knows that
> Anakin hates going to. Obi-Wan's not
> gonna be throwing his name around
> everywhere he goes, aside from the
> Larses and maybe some close neighbors.
> Still, he adopts the first name Ben just in
> case. It was Owen and Beru's decision to
> give Luke the last name Skywalker in
> reverence to Owen's stepmother and
> Luke's grandmother, Shmi Skywalker.
> Granted, Anakin Skywalker made a name
> for himself throughout the galaxy as a hero
> of the Clone Wars, though he also made
> a name for himself on Tatooine as the
> only human to compete in and win the
> Boonta Eve Podrace. And yet, throughout
> his childhood. Luke never knew anything
> about a Skywalker being a great Jedi or
> a famous Podracer. We can only assume
> that there are many other Skywalkers
> in the galaxy and Luke never made the
> connection or heard of these stories.
>
> [image]

Answer (score 8):

In fact, this worked very well, as Luke remained hidden from Vader and the Emperor until his protector decided to reveal him. Even after that, It took time for them to realize Luke's lineage.

As I explain [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/6627/45), they where not searching for him because they thought Amidala died before giving birth. Even after the first death star's destruction, the emperor didn't realize Luke was Anakin's son before he started his training with Yoda.

Answer (score 5):

At best I'd say this is a plot hole and any attempts to explain it are just good tries at ret-conning what we know about how the OT turns out (i.e. Luke and Kenobi were never found) into the story.

Worse, the blame seems to be placed squarely on the prequels.

- Luke's dad is discussed in the OT--and they may mention his first name--but I'm pretty sure Anakin Skywalker made its debut in the prequels. Meaning Skywalker could have been Luke's ingognito name until Lucas ruined it. (Vader says Skywalker, but only after he knows Luke's real parentage, so any name he went by would have been said with gravity.)
- Same with Tatooine. We don't know Anakin is from there until TPM. Lars and Veru could have been moved there in hiding and ANH the first time we ever hear about it.
- Lastly, even Obi-Wan could have been explained by a better plot for the prequels. Obviously Vader knows him by that name, based on their chat before the duel on the Death Star, but if RoTS would have ended with Vader thinking Obi-Wan was dead, then him going by Old Ben on some random planet on the Rim would have been plenty low key.

Comment: True! I cannot accept it as a canonic answer though.

Comment: Nope. From the script:

LUKE
You told me Vader betrayed and murdered my father.

BEN
You father was seduced by the dark side of the Force. He ceased to be 
Anakin Skywalker
and became Darth Vader. When that happened, the good man who was your 
father was destroyed. So what I have told you was true... from a 
certain point of view.

Comment: And the Emperor refers to Luke in Empire as "the son of Skywalker" *before* the parentage is revealed.

Comment: The Obi-Wan would make sense in terms of him using Luke's incognito name, but it's true that the Emperor part from ESB doesn't jive with my answer. So I guess Lucas ruined it as early as 1980. :)

Answer (score 2):

From what I have heard originally while the original movie was filmed it was not Lucas' intent to have Darth Vader be Anakin Skywalker so that explains why Luke would have gone by his true last name...

Comment: From an out of universe perspective, yes, but generally questions on this site are looking for an in universe explanation.

Comment: This is the only valid answer. Every attempt for an in-universe answer in mind games and retconning.

Answer (score 1):

It was a perfect ruse if you think about it. As the accepted answer already mentioned the bad memories meant that vader would not go voluntarily to tatooine and if he did he would not stay for long.

And with so many planets in the galaxy a similar name would not be that much out of order. Now in the new canon (the comics) Vader even had met luke personally fighting the young yedi after the death stars destruction and cleaning the floor with him.

He still was intrigued enough by him to send a bounty hunter after him. And only when the puzzle parts fell into place......ben kenobi training luke, giving him anakins old light saber AND luke being from Tatooine and a jedi AND having the Skywalker name.....only then vader understood the ruse that happened and that he had a son.

Thus hiding luke right in the open was the most sure way for people to overlook him (especially as nobody had searched for him or was aware that he was force sensitive).

Answer (score 0):

To add to the best answer above, Skywalker may very well have been a slave name or a bastard name on Tatooine or even in that part of the Galaxy.

I personally like this because it concludes that twice a Skywalker (slave/bastard) goes on to become the most powerful individual in the Galaxy.

For me the only plot hole is that Vader never once noticed in 20 years that his "family" Mr. and Mrs. Lars were raising a Skywalker.

Comment: Actually, according to the annotated screenplays and the original novelizations, Owen Lars was originally meant to be Ben's brother, and not related to Anakin at all. It wasn't until the prequels that this became an issue. Also, this adds nothing to the existing answers.

Answer (score -1):

Seems no one thought of perhaps the obvious possibility, that Skywalker may not be so unique of a name? We are talking about a populations the size of a galaxy after all.

Comment: That possibility has [already been mentioned.](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/110184/5184)

Comment: I looked again, I don't see an answer that includes it

Comment: Right in the answer I linked: "And with so many planets in the galaxy a similar name would not be that much out of order. "

Comment: @Escoce - that suggestion is also in comments on this page