# When does Darth Vader realise Palpatine lied to him about his killing Padme?

Tags: star-wars, darth-vader, revenge-of-the-sith, the-empire-strikes-back

At the end of Episode III [we see](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-Revenge-of-the-Sith.html):

> DARTH VADER: (continuing) Where is Padme? Is she safe, is she all right?
>
> DARTH SIDIOUS moves closer to the half droid/half man.
>
> DARTH SIDIOUS: I'm afraid she died. ... it seems in your anger, you killed her.
>
> A LOW GROAN emanates from Vader's mask. Suddenly everything in the room begins to implode, including some of the DROIDS.
>
> DARTH VADER: I couldn't have! She was alive! I felt her! She was alive! It's impossible! No!!!

So at this point Vader believes he has unintentionally killed Padme, and by implication her children, and his children.

In [Episode V](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-The-Empire-Strikes-Back.html) we see:

> VADER: What is thy bidding, my master?
>
> EMPEROR: There is a great disturbance in the Force.
>
> VADER: I have felt it.
>
> EMPEROR: We have a new enemy - Luke Skywalker.
>
> VADER: Yes, my master.
>
> EMPEROR: He could destroy us.
>
> VADER: He's just a boy.  Obi-Wan can no longer help him.
>
> EMPEROR:  The Force is strong with him.  The son of Skywalker must not become a Jedi.
>
> VADER: If he could be turned, he would become a powerful ally.
>
> EMPEROR: Yes.  Yes.  He would be a great asset.  Can it be done?
>
> VADER: He will join us or die, my master.

So we see Vader realizes that his son is alive, and by implication, that he was lied to by Palpatine.

My question is: **When does Darth Vader realise Palpatine lied to him about his killing Padme?**

Comment: She did die due to his actions... So Palpatine was telling the truth... From a certain point of view... Hey if it's good for the Jedi it's good for the Sith

Comment: [When and how does Vader learn that Luke is his son?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/80479/when-and-how-does-vader-learn-that-luke-is-his-son?lq=1)

Comment: @CearonO'Flynn Yeah, I dunno.  I wouldn't buy that.

Comment: @MishaRosnach it wasn't really serious hence in a comment

Comment: This answer has the answer http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/81390/56279

Comment: Just because she died, didn't necessarily mean they weren't able to save the twins, especially given how close to term she was and that their medical science is more advanced than ours.  He did know, but I am just saying it was necessarily true that him killing Padme also meant the death of his unborn offspring.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The Darth Vader marvel comic series that takes place post "A New Hope" is when he realizes that Palpatine was lying to him.

When Vader has Boba Fett track down the pilot who blew up the Death Star, Fett returns and says he has a name, and it's "Skywalker".

*(Interpretation time: Vader realizes the Force in that pilot, with that last name, things click)*

The comic ends with Vader hearing the name and shattering all of the windows in the room he is standing in.