# Is there only a single Skywalker family?

Tags: star-wars, names, luke-skywalker, anakin-skywalker, genealogy

Given the size of the Empire, it seems highly probable that names would be reused. Although I'm not aware of any in canon, there must be other Skywalkers in the galaxy, leading me to my question.

Are there other Skywalkers in the galaxy, and are they mentioned in canon? Does Luke have any third cousins twice removed (etc.)?

Bonus points if you can attest to force sensitivity among the surname.

Comment: There's a metric crap-ton of Skywalkers, but they're all related to Shmi; http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Skywalker_family

Comment: @Valorum I just find it odd that when the Emperor mentions "Luke Skywalker" or just "Skywalker", that even though Anakin is a Skywalker (and due to a retcon) doesn't know about his son, he immediately makes the connection to the correct Luke rather than the (maybe?) billions of others.

Comment: related: [When and how does Vader learn that Luke is his son?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/80479/5184)

Comment: @Anoplexian - It may be quite a common name, but the Emperor and Darth don't believe in coincidences.

Comment: @Anoplexian - by ESB, Vader has been chasing the rebels for three years, and would have known which Skywalker was responsible for the destruction of the Death Star and was now a hero/leader in the alliance. There are probably a number of Trumps in the world, but who are you thinking about now I've mentioned the name. Also - The Force

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Main (Disney) Canon.

Only three '*Skywalkers*' are mentioned in the main canon and all are direct relatives of each other:

- Shmi Skywalker

↓

- Anakin Skywalker

↓

- Luke Skywalker

Rey takes the surname Skywalker at the end of *Rise of Skywalker*, honouring Luke and Leia's contribution to her training).

Shmi also has four other known relatives; her parents (who were captured and enslaved at the same time as her), Leia Organa (her granddaughter) and Ben Solo (her great-grandson).

---

### "Legends" Canon

Excluding [relatives of Shmi](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Skywalker_family), it would appear that there are indeed *other* Skywalkers, potentially even some living on Tatooine (at least according to Vader).

> *According to a captured Rebel whom Darth Vader interrogated on the
> planet Centares, that was the name of the X-wing pilot who had
> destroyed the Death Star.*
>
> *Luke Skywalker.*
>
> *Even while inspecting his nearly completed flagship, the Super Star
> Destroyer Executor, at the Starship Yards of Fondor, Vader could not
> get Luke Skywalker out of his mind. He silently chewed on the name,
> and considered the fact that the boy had been born three years after
> the death of Shmi Skywalker. To the best of his knowledge, Anakin
> Skywalker had been his mother's only living blood relative.*
>
> ***Could there have been other Skywalkers from Tatooine? Vader allowed
> the possibility. After all, it wasn't an entirely uncommon name in the
> galaxy.***
>
> <sub><sup>[The Rise and Fall of Darth Vader](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Rise_and_Fall_of_Darth_Vader)</sup></sub>

Comment: +2 for a well researched answer, but -1 for not including Leia Skywalker. :P

Comment: @Anoplexian - I considered it, but decided against it on the grounds that she doesn't go by that name.